# How does CollectionViewSource work?

Tags: wpf, xaml, collectionviewsource

Can anyone tell me how I should set the right property in CollectionViewSource in XAML on Windows 8?

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="itemsViewSource"     
        Source="{Binding Items}"
        d:Source="{Binding AllTasks, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:TaskItems,  IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
```

x:name is the Name of the object. What's source? What's the difference between d:Source and Source? Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) for this is pretty good.

As the documentation suggests [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.source.aspx) is the collection object your pointing to. Example `ObservableCollection<T>`

The first link also shows a usage example. Basically in plain English CollectionViewSource is used to filter/group/sort data in a list/collection and then use the result in a view

As for your doubt about `d:` I cannot be sure without seeing your xmlns declaration in your top level element, but assuming defaults `d:` corresponds to design time data/attributes

[Design time attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff602277%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

It's used to help design and visualise your UI in design time when live data may not be available.